# PHP - How to create a file dynamically?

Tags: php

I want to create PHP files dynamically. Static HTML code works fine, but when I want to insert PHP code, which contains a "window.location" command, my script directly send me to that page, without fulling the "if(isset())"-condition.

Somehow a simple echo doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
 public function suche()
 {
   echo "if(isset(\$_POST['searchit']))
   {
    \$suchbegriff = \$_POST['suchbegriff'];

    \$anfangsbuchstabe = substr(\$suchbegriff, 0, 1);

    <script type='text/javascript' language='Javascript'>window.location = '/".$anfangsbuchstabe."/".$suchbegriff.".php'</script>
  }";
 }
```

Comment: Just what exactly are you trying to do, and how in the world do you expect it to work?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really writing to a php file that you want to call / execute later in a different request, you need to make sure the php is recognized as php, now it is just text.

So you would need something like:

```
public function suche()
 {
   echo "<?php if(isset(\$_POST['searchit']))
   {
    \$suchbegriff = \$_POST['suchbegriff'];

    \$anfangsbuchstabe = substr(\$suchbegriff, 0, 1);
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript' language='Javascript'>window.location = '/".$anfangsbuchstabe."/".$suchbegriff.".php'</script>
<?php
  }
?>";
 }
```

Note that I have added the `php` opening and closing tags.

Comment: @jeroen..thanks man!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a file, you can't just echo something, you have to write it to a file. You can use [`file_put_contents(string $filename, mixed $contents)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for this, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the variables. As you can see in the colors of the pasted PHP, the variables will get executed.

Escape them with `\`, and do the same for the double quotes (`"`)

Also, what I noticed as well, is that you're `echo`ing your code. Echo-ing PHP code will not ever actually execute the code.

You can execute PHP code with `eval`, but this is **VERY UNSAFE**. Judging by what I can see from your question, you're not experienced enough to count for all security risks. Don't use it.